# Binding ComboBox to Enum throw exception

Tags: c#, wpf

Didn't find out why this is not working :

I have a `ComboBox` in a `UserControl` where its `ItemSource` bind to an `Enum` using `ObjectDataProvider` :

```
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:CMiX.ViewModels"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Blend" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="ViewModels:BlendMode"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>


<ComboBox
    SelectedItem="{Binding BlendMode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Blend}}">
</ComboBox>
```

The Enum is fairly simple :

```
namespace CMiX.ViewModels
{
    public enum BlendMode
    {
        Normal,
        Add,
        Subtract
    };
}
```

Finally the `SelectedItem` bind to the `ViewModel` that carry the property `BlendMode` :

```
private BlendMode _blendMode;
public BlendMode BlendMode
{
    get => _blendMode;
    set => SetAndNotify(ref _blendMode, value);
}
```

Now if I want to run the application I got this :

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.'
```

Unfortunately I really don't know why.

Comment: use   DisplayMemberPath="Name"    SelectedValuePath="Name" in combobox

Comment: if I use DisplayMemberPath="Name" no error, but also no text is showing up inside the ComboBox.

Comment: have you added reference ?

Comment: Like   xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:your namespace"

Comment: yes :     xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:CMiX.ViewModels"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Comment: Find the panel hosting the ComboBox (Grid,Window, etc.) and move the declaration of DataObjectProvider there, e.g. <Window.Resources><ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Blend" .../></Window.Resources>

Comment: it's already the case, the ComboBox is within a usercontrol and the ObjectDataProvider is a resource of this usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

The `MethodName` should be `GetNames` instead of `GetValues` then it works.